# Desktop System Setting missing

Tags: desktop

I've just upgraded to Juno, and have noticed that I'm missing the Desktop setting in System Settings. I found this as a result of looking for why I can't right-click the desktop. It's just not there. [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell wasn't installed for some reason.

```
sudo apt install switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell
```

Solved the problem.